# Access the CSS3 translate transform offsets using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am using JavaScript to move an element using the `translate` function of the `-webkit-transform` property:

```
node.style.WebkitTransform = "translate(" + leftPos + "px, 0px)"
```

The value of `leftPos` is calculated during run time.

In another method I want to move this node from its current position. This method does not know the value of `lastPos`.

**How can I get the `leftPos` value from the DOM without keeping track of it?**

One obvious solution is parsing the property value:

```
node.style.WebkitTransform; // returns "translate(-Xpx, 0px)"
```

I can parse this, but it doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: You're probably going to have to parse it.

Comment: Since you're talking about 'optimal' keeping the track is optimal than working with the DOM

Comment: @gengkev: not necessarily! :) You can access the parameters directly, though personally I'd go with storing the value as an attribute of the element.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't do it this way, personally—see the caveats for why.

Still, it is possible. The interfaces aren't very well known, so I'll explain how it's done for anyone who's interested.

### How to do it

You can access the property directly by drilling through the DOM interfaces for CSS transforms, particularly [`CSSTransformValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/#csstransformvalue-interface) ([`WebKitCSSTransformValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/WebKitCSSTransformValueClassReference/WebKitCSSTransformValue/WebKitCSSTransformValue.html) in WebKit), through which you can access parameters to the transform functions:

```js
leftPos = node.style.getPropertyCSSValue('-webkit-transform')[0][0].getFloatValue(CSSPrimitiveValue.CSS_PX);
```

Let's break that down and take a look at the interfaces involved:

- [`getPropertyCSSValue('-webkit-transform')`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration-getPropertyCSSValue) → [`CSSValueList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSValueList). (All transforms set on element.)

  - `[0]` → [`WebKitCSSTransformValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/WebKitCSSTransformValueClassReference/WebKitCSSTransformValue/WebKitCSSTransformValue.html) (First transform function applied to this element.)

    - `[0]` → [`CSSPrimitiveValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSPrimitiveValue) (First argument to the `translate` function.)

### Caveats

- My personal preference would be to just store the property somewhere (like a `data-*` attribute on the element) or even use a regex on the property value, and maybe use WebKit animation to do the heavy lifting for you. Accessing it this way is tedious, messy and involves trekking along some less well-tread paths through the DOM.
- This method *will not work in Firefox*, even if you use `-moz-transform`. [Mozilla only supports `getPropertyCSSValue` on the results of `getComputedStyle`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62682); this gives you the transform matrix, in which case you would use `window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyCSSValue('-webkit-transform')[0][4].getFloatValue(CSSPrimitiveValue.CSS_PX)` to access the translate-X value. (Assuming that's the only transform applied.)
- The W3C has been talking about [deprecating these interfaces](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2003Oct/0347.html) for years in favour of the [CSSOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/). Progress on this was [stalled at time of writing](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2009Oct/0349.html), but that's certainly no longer the case—*caveat emptor*!

Comment: Great answer, thanks for noting the wg-discussion  :)

Answer (score -4):

Maybe jQuery can help you: [jQuery: offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

EDIT: [jQuery: position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) is what you want

Comment: `jQuery.offset` does take CSS transforms into account in WebKit, but note that it measures offset position relative to the _whole document_; this may not be what Dean wants! :)

Comment: You might be right in some case, but not in this. `jQuery.offset` measures the offset to the nearest anchestor

Comment: `jQuery.offset` (http://api.jquery.com/offset/) definitely returns position relative to the document, not the offset parent; maybe you're thinking of `jQuery.position` (http://api.jquery.com/position/)? From the docs: "The `.offset()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element _relative to the document_. Contrast this with `.position()`, which retrieves the current position _relative to the offset parent_." To demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/4ncGZ